# Creating new RadioButtons Android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Hi I'm trying to create an app for Android and in order to develop it i need to navigate through different pages and questions. For this task I have defined a radiogroup with some radiobuttons. However these radiobuttons remain the same when the user goes the next or previous question ( it only changes the text but not the selected answer, which is always the selected one for every one). For that reason i think I need to create new RadioButtons when I go to the next question but that save the state if I go to the previous question.

Here is part of my code if you could help
XML:

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/respuestas3RG"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/imagenenunciado3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/respuesta3A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A. RespuestaA"/>
   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/respuesta3B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B. RespuestaB"/>
   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/respuesta3C"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C. RespuestaC"/>
   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/respuesta3D"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D. RespuestaD"/>
   </RadioGroup>
```

Java:

```
bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {
                posicion = posicion +1;
                questions.Next();       
                currentQuestion();



            }
```

I don't know if the best option is to create all the radioButtons at the start or generate them when the user goes through the next question.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to recreate it, save the state(answer) before you clear the checks with 
[setChecked(false);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html#setChecked%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks for your help wtsang02. However, when I go back to the previous questions those radiobuttons are also unchecked even if I have answered them.

Comment: As I said, save the state of it before you advance to the next question. So if you go back to the question you can reload that state.

Comment: Thank you wtsang but I'm a bit lost of how to save the state in the radiobuttons. More help will be very appreciated because i haven't found information on any other page.

Comment: Get all the radiobuttons,and loop it: if(radiobutton.isChecked(){//its checked }else{//its unchecked}

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a different activity for every page. The only reason why I would prefer a single activity is for some kind of question game.

**If you want it to be in the same Activity:**

You could also use a [LayouInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflat the very same xml to multiple Views. Each for a seperate Page. That way your page state keeps the same because it is stored in the related View and not inside your Activity. Changing back and forth would be a simple call to

> setContentView(yourViewArray[page]);

And you can put all the validating stuff at the end.

But first you should check if you really want to put all pages into the same Activity.

Comment: Thank you MAx. At the moment i have different tests (activities) and within these ones there are included these pages so i don't think creaing for instante 30 activities (30 questions) for only one test is the best option

Comment: As mentioned as an alternative way. Try inflating your XML multiple times. The inflater will return an View Object which represents your View. Just do this as often as needed, put tehm all into an Array and use each for a new page. If someone hits "next" just do setContentView(myArray[currentPage++]) and your next View in the array is displayed. Very handy, but dont forget to check array bounderies.